# Wi-Fi connection from Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, wireless-networking

I am trying to connecting to Wi-Fi from using my Windows 7. But as my keyboard is not working properly I am not able to switch on the Wi-Fi.

Is there any hack I can do to switch on the Wi-Fi from Windows 7 or Linux?

Comment: Fix your keyboard first, then worry about wi-fi.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to turn the wireless on and off using the [Windows Mobility Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Using-Windows-Mobility-Center)

> To open Windows Mobility Center
>
> Open Windows Mobility Center by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Mobile PC, and then clicking Windows Mobility Center.

You should see something like this:

[image]

Where you can click to turn the wireless on or off.

It appears that this is only enabled by default on laptops, notebooks and netbooks, you can enable it for desktop systems [here](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/220621-windows-mobility-center-enable-desktop-computer.html)

Answer (score 1):

On-screen keyboard perhaps? I see it has a Fn key. [Type without using the keyboard (On-Screen Keyboard)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Type-without-using-the-keyboard-On-Screen-Keyboard).

Yup, just tried it and when you you click on Fn, the F1 through F12 keys are shown, so it should work.

Comment: Good old onscreen keyboard, such a useful tool... +1